# Ogre - Cannot find requested emitter type. in ParticleSystemManager::_createEmitter

Tags: c++, ogre

I'm trying to run TinyOgre from [this tutorial](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=Ogre%20Wiki%20Tutorial%20Framework) but I still get the following message:

> OGRE EXCEPTION(2:InvalidParameterException): Cannot find requested emitter type. in ParticleSystemManager::_createEmitter at
>   C:/Intel/INDE/OgreSDK_1-9-0/Ogre/OgreMain/src/OgreParticleSystemManager.cpp
>   (line 270)

Here is my code:

TinyOgre.cpp

```
/*
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Filename:    TinyOgre.cpp
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

This source file is part of the
   ___                 __    __ _ _    _ 
  /___\__ _ _ __ ___  / / /\ \ (_) | _(_)
 //  // _` | '__/ _ \ \ \/  \/ / | |/ / |
/ \_// (_| | | |  __/  \  /\  /| |   <| |
\___/ \__, |_|  \___|   \/  \/ |_|_|\_\_|
      |___/                              
      Tutorial Framework
      http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
#include "TinyOgre.h"

#include <OgreLogManager.h>
#include <OgreViewport.h>
#include <OgreConfigFile.h>
#include <OgreEntity.h>
#include <OgreWindowEventUtilities.h>

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TinyOgre::TinyOgre(void)
    : mRoot(0),
    mCamera(0),
    mSceneMgr(0),
    mWindow(0),
    mResourcesCfg(Ogre::StringUtil::BLANK),
    mPluginsCfg(Ogre::StringUtil::BLANK)
{
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TinyOgre::~TinyOgre(void)
{
    delete mRoot;
}

bool TinyOgre::go(void)
{
#ifdef _DEBUG
    mResourcesCfg = "resources_d.cfg";
    mPluginsCfg = "plugins_d.cfg";
#else
    mResourcesCfg = "resources.cfg";
    mPluginsCfg = "plugins.cfg";
#endif

    // construct Ogre::Root
    mRoot = new Ogre::Root(mPluginsCfg);

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // setup resources
    // Load resource paths from config file
    Ogre::ConfigFile cf;
    cf.load(mResourcesCfg);

    // Go through all sections & settings in the file
    Ogre::ConfigFile::SectionIterator seci = cf.getSectionIterator();

    Ogre::String secName, typeName, archName;
    while (seci.hasMoreElements())
    {
        secName = seci.peekNextKey();
        Ogre::ConfigFile::SettingsMultiMap *settings = seci.getNext();
        Ogre::ConfigFile::SettingsMultiMap::iterator i;
        for (i = settings->begin(); i != settings->end(); ++i)
        {
            typeName = i->first;
            archName = i->second;
            Ogre::ResourceGroupManager::getSingleton().addResourceLocation(
                archName, typeName, secName);
        }
    }
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // configure
    // Show the configuration dialog and initialise the system
    // You can skip this and use root.restoreConfig() to load configuration
    // settings if you were sure there are valid ones saved in ogre.cfg
    if(mRoot->restoreConfig() || mRoot->showConfigDialog())
    {
        // If returned true, user clicked OK so initialise
        // Here we choose to let the system create a default rendering window by passing 'true'
        mWindow = mRoot->initialise(true, "TinyOgre Render Window");
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // choose scenemanager
    // Get the SceneManager, in this case a generic one
    mSceneMgr = mRoot->createSceneManager(Ogre::ST_GENERIC);
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // create camera
    // Create the camera
    mCamera = mSceneMgr->createCamera("PlayerCam");

    // Position it at 500 in Z direction
    mCamera->setPosition(Ogre::Vector3(0,0,80));
    // Look back along -Z
    mCamera->lookAt(Ogre::Vector3(0,0,-300));
    mCamera->setNearClipDistance(5);

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // create viewports
    // Create one viewport, entire window
    Ogre::Viewport* vp = mWindow->addViewport(mCamera);
    vp->setBackgroundColour(Ogre::ColourValue(0,0,0));

    // Alter the camera aspect ratio to match the viewport
    mCamera->setAspectRatio(
        Ogre::Real(vp->getActualWidth()) / Ogre::Real(vp->getActualHeight()));
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Set default mipmap level (NB some APIs ignore this)
    Ogre::TextureManager::getSingleton().setDefaultNumMipmaps(5);
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Create any resource listeners (for loading screens)
    //createResourceListener();
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // load resources
    Ogre::ResourceGroupManager::getSingleton().initialiseAllResourceGroups();
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Create the scene
    Ogre::Entity* ogreHead = mSceneMgr->createEntity("Head", "ogrehead.mesh");

    Ogre::SceneNode* headNode = mSceneMgr->getRootSceneNode()->createChildSceneNode();
    headNode->attachObject(ogreHead);

    // Set ambient light
    mSceneMgr->setAmbientLight(Ogre::ColourValue(0.5, 0.5, 0.5));

    // Create a light
    Ogre::Light* l = mSceneMgr->createLight("MainLight");
    l->setPosition(20,80,50);
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    while(true)
    {
        // Pump window messages for nice behaviour
        Ogre::WindowEventUtilities::messagePump();

        if(mWindow->isClosed())
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Render a frame
        if(!mRoot->renderOneFrame()) return false;
    }

    // We should never be able to reach this corner
    // but return true to calm down our compiler
    return true;
}


#if OGRE_PLATFORM == OGRE_PLATFORM_WIN32
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include "windows.h"
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#if OGRE_PLATFORM == OGRE_PLATFORM_WIN32
    INT WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE, LPSTR strCmdLine, INT )
#else
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
#endif
    {
        // Create application object
        TinyOgre app;

        try {
            app.go();
        } catch( Ogre::Exception& e ) {
#if OGRE_PLATFORM == OGRE_PLATFORM_WIN32
            MessageBox( NULL, e.getFullDescription().c_str(), "An exception has occured!", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR | MB_TASKMODAL);
#else
            std::cerr << "An exception has occured: " <<
                e.getFullDescription().c_str() << std::endl;
#endif
        }

        return 0;
    }

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

TinyOgre.h

```
/*
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Filename:    TinyOgre.h
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

This source file is part of the
   ___                 __    __ _ _    _ 
  /___\__ _ _ __ ___  / / /\ \ (_) | _(_)
 //  // _` | '__/ _ \ \ \/  \/ / | |/ / |
/ \_// (_| | | |  __/  \  /\  /| |   <| |
\___/ \__, |_|  \___|   \/  \/ |_|_|\_\_|
      |___/                              
      Tutorial Framework
      http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
#ifndef __TinyOgre_h_
#define __TinyOgre_h_

#include <OgreRoot.h>
#include <OgreCamera.h>
#include <OgreSceneManager.h>
#include <OgreRenderWindow.h>

class TinyOgre
{
public:
    TinyOgre(void);
    virtual ~TinyOgre(void);
    bool go(void);
protected:
    Ogre::Root *mRoot;
    Ogre::Camera* mCamera;
    Ogre::SceneManager* mSceneMgr;
    Ogre::RenderWindow* mWindow;
    Ogre::String mResourcesCfg;
    Ogre::String mPluginsCfg;
};

#endif // #ifndef __TinyOgre_h_
```

My resources.cfg is following (I've composed it from some other tutorials on web):

```
# Resources required by the sample browser and most samples.
[Essential]
Zip=C:/Intel/INDE/OgreSDK_1-9-0/Ogre/Samples/Media/packs/SdkTrays.zip
Zip=C:/Intel/INDE/OgreSDK_1-9-0/Ogre/Samples/Media/packs/profiler.zip
FileSystem=C:/Intel/INDE/OgreSDK_1-9-0/Ogre/Samples/Media/thumbnails

# Common sample resources needed by many of the samples.
# Rarely used resources should be separately loaded by the
# samples which require them.
[Popular]
FileSystem=C:/Intel/INDE/OgreSDK_1-9-0/Ogre/Samples/Media/fonts
FileSystem=C:/Intel/INDE/OgreSDK_1-9-0/Ogre/Samples/Media/materials/programs
FileSystem=C:/Intel/INDE/OgreSDK_1-9-0/Ogre/Samples/Media/materials/programs/Cg
FileSystem=C:/Intel/INDE/OgreSDK_1-9-0/Ogre/Samples/Media/materials/programs/GLSL
FileSystem=C:/Intel/INDE/OgreSDK_1-9-0/Ogre/Samples/Media/materials/programs/GLSL150
FileSystem=C:/Intel/INDE/OgreSDK_1-9-0/Ogre/Samples/Media/materials/programs/GLSL400
FileSystem=C:/Intel/INDE/OgreSDK_1-9-0/Ogre/Samples/Media/materials/programs/GLSLES
FileSystem=C:/Intel/INDE/OgreSDK_1-9-0/Ogre/Samples/Media/materials/programs/HLSL
FileSystem=C:/Intel/INDE/OgreSDK_1-9-0/Ogre/Samples/Media/materials/scripts
FileSystem=C:/Intel/INDE/OgreSDK_1-9-0/Ogre/Samples/Media/materials/textures
FileSystem=C:/Intel/INDE/OgreSDK_1-9-0/Ogre/Samples/Media/materials/textures/nvidia
FileSystem=C:/Intel/INDE/OgreSDK_1-9-0/Ogre/Samples/Media/materials/scripts/SSAO
FileSystem=C:/Intel/INDE/OgreSDK_1-9-0/Ogre/Samples/Media/materials/textures/SSAO
FileSystem=C:/Intel/INDE/OgreSDK_1-9-0/Ogre/Samples/Media/RTShaderLib/Cg
FileSystem=C:/Intel/INDE/OgreSDK_1-9-0/Ogre/Samples/Media/RTShaderLib/GLSL
FileSystem=C:/Intel/INDE/OgreSDK_1-9-0/Ogre/Samples/Media/models
FileSystem=C:/Intel/INDE/OgreSDK_1-9-0/Ogre/Samples/Media/particle
FileSystem=C:/Intel/INDE/OgreSDK_1-9-0/Ogre/Samples/Media/DeferredShadingMedia
FileSystem=C:/Intel/INDE/OgreSDK_1-9-0/Ogre/Samples/Media/PCZAppMedia
FileSystem=C:/Intel/INDE/OgreSDK_1-9-0/Ogre/Samples/Media/RTShaderLib
FileSystem=C:/Intel/INDE/OgreSDK_1-9-0/Ogre/Samples/Media/RTShaderLib/materials
FileSystem=C:/Intel/INDE/OgreSDK_1-9-0/Ogre/Samples/Media/PCZAppMedia
FileSystem=C:/Intel/INDE/OgreSDK_1-9-0/Ogre/Samples/Media/volumeTerrain
Zip=C:/Intel/INDE/OgreSDK_1-9-0/Ogre/Samples/Media/packs/cubemap.zip
Zip=C:/Intel/INDE/OgreSDK_1-9-0/Ogre/Samples/Media/packs/cubemapsJS.zip
Zip=C:/Intel/INDE/OgreSDK_1-9-0/Ogre/Samples/Media/packs/dragon.zip
Zip=C:/Intel/INDE/OgreSDK_1-9-0/Ogre/Samples/Media/packs/fresneldemo.zip
Zip=C:/Intel/INDE/OgreSDK_1-9-0/Ogre/Samples/Media/packs/ogretestmap.zip
Zip=C:/Intel/INDE/OgreSDK_1-9-0/Ogre/Samples/Media/packs/ogredance.zip
Zip=C:/Intel/INDE/OgreSDK_1-9-0/Ogre/Samples/Media/packs/Sinbad.zip
Zip=C:/Intel/INDE/OgreSDK_1-9-0/Ogre/Samples/Media/packs/skybox.zip
Zip=C:/Intel/INDE/OgreSDK_1-9-0/Ogre/Samples/Media/volumeTerrain/volumeTerrainBig.zip

FileSystem=C:/Intel/INDE/OgreSDK_1-9-0/Ogre/Samples/ParticleFX

[General]
FileSystem=C:/Intel/INDE/OgreSDK_1-9-0/Ogre/Samples/Media

# Materials for visual tests
[Tests]
FileSystem=C:/Intel/INDE/OgreSDK_1-9-0/Ogre/Tests/Media
```

I have noticed that when I comment following lines:

```
#FileSystem=C:/Intel/INDE/OgreSDK_1-9-0/Ogre/Samples/Media/materials/programs/GLSL
#FileSystem=C:/Intel/INDE/OgreSDK_1-9-0/Ogre/Samples/Media/materials/programs/GLSL150
#FileSystem=C:/Intel/INDE/OgreSDK_1-9-0/Ogre/Samples/Media/materials/programs/GLSL400
#FileSystem=C:/Intel/INDE/OgreSDK_1-9-0/Ogre/Samples/Media/materials/programs/GLSLES
#FileSystem=C:/Intel/INDE/OgreSDK_1-9-0/Ogre/Samples/Media/materials/programs/HLSL
#FileSystem=C:/Intel/INDE/OgreSDK_1-9-0/Ogre/Samples/Media/RTShaderLib/Cg
#FileSystem=C:/Intel/INDE/OgreSDK_1-9-0/Ogre/Samples/Media/RTShaderLib/GLSL
```

then I get different error message:

> OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource
>   DualQuaternion_Common.glsl in resource group Popular or any other
>   group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at
>   C:/Intel/INDE/OgreSDK_1-9-0/Ogre/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp
>   (line 756)

If I comment following lines:

```
#FileSystem=C:/Intel/INDE/OgreSDK_1-9-0/Ogre/Samples/Media/materials/programs/GLSL
#FileSystem=C:/Intel/INDE/OgreSDK_1-9-0/Ogre/Samples/Media/materials/programs/GLSL150
#FileSystem=C:/Intel/INDE/OgreSDK_1-9-0/Ogre/Samples/Media/materials/programs/GLSL400
#FileSystem=C:/Intel/INDE/OgreSDK_1-9-0/Ogre/Samples/Media/materials/programs/GLSLES
#FileSystem=C:/Intel/INDE/OgreSDK_1-9-0/Ogre/Samples/Media/materials/programs/HLSL
```

then I get this error message:

> OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource
>   shadows.glsl in resource group Popular or any other group. in
>   ResourceGroupManager::openResource at
>   C:/Intel/INDE/OgreSDK_1-9-0/Ogre/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp
>   (line 756)

Let me further clarify my situation; we are using ogre in our current project for some visualization and math that it provides (personally I do not do ogre but other project parts). Nowadays I wanted to compile "hello world" ogre project and start to playing with. I'm using VisualStudio 2013 and Ogre 1.9. I suspect that the problem might be that I have ogre installed not according to wiki but instead it is copied from another PC. But I'm 100% sure that this is working installation because I have several team members which are using same installation (same paths, same environment variables etc) and for our project it is working fine, so I would not to like mess with current installation. For example [following code](http://pastebin.com/Gk3aJM1L) which is also using ogre is working fine for me (but this example is not using resources.cfg). Thanks

PS: firstly I wanted to post this to ogre forums but seems that registration is broken (no mail arrived after registering) so if anybody can re post it I will be glad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as if you did not load the "Plugin_ParticleFX" in your application. Make sure that it is listed in your "plugins.cfg". This plugin will then provide the emitter types listed on the [dedicated Ogre3D wiki page](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/ParticleFX+plugin).

---

Forum: The registration works. If the activation mail somehow did not reach you, please [get in touch](http://www.ogre3d.org/contact) with us and we can easily sort that out.

Comment: Thank you. Adding `Plugin=Plugin_ParticleFX` to the `plugins.cfg` does the trick.